# Intellj doesn't recognise correct Maven version

Tags: linux, maven, intellij-idea

I have a custom Maven set as the home path in Settings, but in Terminal I see another version.
How can I make the terminal recognise the correct version? I don't have a custom shell defined.

[image]

**EDIT:** This is the result of enabling the option `delegate the Build action to Maven` and clicking on `Build project`. No output?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Changing the version of Maven in IntelliJ doesn't change the version that the terminal inside IntelliJ uses since that's from your PATH variable.

You can, however, [delegate the Build action to Maven](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/delegate-build-and-run-actions-to-maven.html#delegate_to_maven) in IntelliJ or open the project using the pom.xml file, which imports the project as a Maven project. And then you can press the Build button to build the project using the Maven version you have chosen inside of IntelliJ.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the answer. I'm not sure what command that "Build project" actually runs as I'm not getting any output.. (I have 2 profiles in my pom named `build-app` and `build-backend`)

Comment: I've updated my question

Comment: @alfredopacino You should be able to press "Edit Configurations..." on the dropdown next to the Build button to build separate profiles, if you have no default target. You also might want to remove the .idea/ folder and reopen the project using the pom.xml file instead of the folder, as IntelliJ sometimes can get a tad buggy.